# folder and files selection in .net

Tags: .net, components

I want the control component which can provide access to all file sistem like a folder browser dialog but with supprot of which i can select many folders and file. whether there is already such a component in VS 2008 or made by third parties or should I create it myself?

Answer (score 1):

I am decide to use System.Windows.Forms.TreeView